# How is the generalised momentum a covector?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, classical-mechanics

I know that this has been a question asked here before, but I'm still struggling to understand the concept.  V.I. Arnold states that for "the configuration manifold $V$, the 'generalised momentum '$\textbf{p}=\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\textbf{q}}}$ is a cotangent vector.  I'm struggling to see how this works, a co-vector, $dx_i$, at a point $p\in M$ is defined as

$$dx_i:T_PM\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
$$dx_i(\textbf{v})=v_i$$
Where $\textbf{v}\in T_pM$.  So a co-vector should map $\textbf{v}$ to the $i$'th component of $\textbf{v}$.  How would this work for generalised momentum, since it would mean $$\textbf{p}(\textbf{v})=\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\textbf{q}}}(\textbf{v})=v_i$$
But I don't see how this is the case.

Comment: You could also post this on physics stack exchange. And how do you come up with:  $$\textbf{p}(\textbf{v})=\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\textbf{q}}}(\textbf{v})=v_i$$? If you want to do that evaluation, you need to know the lagrangian  $L$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide if your position coordinates are $x$ or $q$, you are using both. Per the last formula, keep using $q$.

As a 1-form $\mathbf p$ is $\sum_i p_i\,dq^i$, so that the evaluation $\mathbf p(\mathbf v)$ has the result $\sum_i p_iv^i$.

Note that as directional derivative $$\frac{∂L}{∂\dot{\mathbf q}}(\mathbf v)=\frac{d}{ds}L(\mathbf q,\dot{\mathbf q}+s\mathbf v)\Big|_{s=0}$$ is indeed a linear functional in $\mathbf v$.

Comment: I think my definition of a 1-form may be wrong as I thought $dx_i(\textbf{v})=v_i$ but here you are saying $\textbf{p}(\textbf{v})=\sum_{i}p_iv_i$.  Is it only the case that $dx_i(\textbf{v})=v_i$ in vector spaces?

Comment: You coordinates are $x=q$. And the coordinate differentials are indeed linear forms returning the coefficients of tangent vectors. But that is not true for general 1-forms or co-vectors that are linear combinations of the coordinate differentials.

Comment: So could we say $\textbf{p}$ is a co-vector because $$\textbf{p}(\textbf{v})=\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\textbf{q}}}(\textbf{v})=\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\textbf{q}}}\begin{pmatrix} v_1\\ \vdots \\ v_n \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} p_1 & ... & p_n\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} v_1\\ \vdots \\ v_n \end{pmatrix}=p_1v_1+...+p_nv_n \in \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: That's what I said. Note that the coordinates of a co-vector are covariant, while the coordinates of a vector are contravariant.

Answer (score 2):

This can be understood by looking at the transform properties of $p_i$. Under a change of general coordinates $q_i \mapsto q'_l(q_i)$, one has $\dot{q}'_l= \frac{\partial q'_l}{\partial q_i}\dot{q}_i$, which implies $\frac{\partial \dot{q}'_l}{\partial \dot{q}_i}= \frac{\partial q'_l}{\partial q_i}$. So we have
\begin{eqnarray}
p_i &\equiv& \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_i}\\
&=& \frac{\partial \dot{q}'_l}{\partial \dot{q}_i}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}'_l}\\
&=& \frac{\partial {q}'_l}{\partial {q}_i} p'_l,
\end{eqnarray}
which shows explicitly that $p_i$ transforms as a covector under the change of general coordinate.

Please Ref. Theodore Frankel "The Geometry of Physics" Section 2.3.